# i cannot get to call the id form the fuctions page it shows that error

Tags: php, get, web, e-commerce

function.php

```
<a href = "details.php?pro_id='.$pro_id.'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Detail</button> </a>
```

===========================================

details.php

```
if(isset($_GET(['pro_id'])){

$product_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
$get_pro = "select * from products where product_id='$product_id'";

$run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
```

Its not working it show the following  error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you
>   can use "null !== func()" instead) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Raj_Cassette\details.php on line 52

Comment: isset() function is for testing vars. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Remove (). $_GET is array so you need to write $_GET['pro_id'] without braces

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst please.... htmlspecialchars is not for escaping values for queries :/

Comment: @nospor, Woah! My bad, coffee is not strong enough this morning, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Side note: You do NOT want to be putting raw get requests in your SQL. You have just assigned $product_id to $_GET['pro_id'] which means anyone can type into the URL some bad script and hack you. You should at a minimum escape your $_GET requests using the mysqli_real_escape_string() the official php manual will explain it better then I ever could :p

Answer (score 5):

$_GET is not a function. It is an array so

Not

`$_GET(['pro_id'])`

But

`$_GET['pro_id']`

Comment: oops ! rookie mistake. Thanks .